# What value to use for Key in CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.setLogins?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Cognito User Pools without any backing Identities; the User Pool login is the only authentication being used ([AWS Cognito Sign-In (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101827/aws-cognito-sign-in-android)). In using the `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` with this, I am running into the issue that what value I'm supposed to use for the Key in the `HashMap` to `setLogins` doesn't appear to be documented. I have found examples for third-party Identity providers ("accounts.google.com", "graph.facebook.com", "www.amazon.com"), but using any of these, or a proposed solution I found somewhere of `"www.cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/[UserPoolID]"` or my original attempt of the name of the User Pool itself, all give an error of `Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName`, and I am running out of ideas to randomly throw at the problem and hope they work.

Any ideas what the correct Key value should be for the HashMap going into `setLogins` for users directly authenticated by the Cognito User Pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exact format should be a string like: "cognito-idp." + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + user pools ID. Here's the code I use - note that my region is different to yours so edit yours to use us-east-1 instead.

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
String iss = "cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/" + AWSConstants.USER_POOLS_POOL_ID;
logins.put(iss, jwtToken);
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

Hope it helps!